# Why does this program crash or hang?

Tags: c++, class, functor

The following code crashes or hangs until memory exhaustion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct Goal {float x; float y;};

class Boxbot 
{
public:
    Boxbot(Goal cgoals[]=0) 
    {
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) { cgoals_[i]=cgoals[i]; }
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) { callbacks(i); }
        
    }
private:
    //Declare member function
    bool check_goal(Goal gl) 
    {
        if (std::sqrt(std::pow(gl.x,2)+std::pow(gl.y,2))<2) {return true;}
        else {return false;}
    }
    //Creating a functor : function object
    struct Callback 
    {
        void operator() (int i) const {
            Boxbot b;
            b.bgoals[i]=b.check_goal(b.cgoals_[i]);
            std::printf("%s is %i\n",b.topicns[i].data(),b.bgoals[i]);
        }
    } callbacks;
    
    //Declare member variables
    bool bgoals[3]={false,false,false};
    Goal cgoals_[3];
    std::string topicns[3]={"robot_1","robot_2","robot_3"};
};

int main() 
{
    Goal cgoals[3] = {{0.3,0.6},{0.9,1.2},{1.5,1.8}};
    Boxbot boxbot(cgoals);
    return 0;
}
```

The result should be as follows, but it freezes.

```
robot_1 is 1
robot_2 is 1
robot_3 is 0
```

All I want to do here is this part:`for (int i=0;i<3;i++) { callbacks(i); }`. In other words, I would like to create a function object in private and access it in public to pass the arguments from main.

The **check_goal()** & **Callback** itself are working fine when I put them in public, so i think the issue is the functor **callbacks** does'nt work in public well... but I do not why.

I tested on [C++ shell](https://stackoverflow.com) version 14, 17, 20.

Comment: Is it really the *compiler* that have a problem, or your program when you're running it?

Comment: Also, the constructor should only *initialize* a base-state of the object, not do possibly long-running calculations. With that in mind, should `for (int i=0;i<3;i++) { callbacks(i); }` really be in the constructor?

Comment: Can't reproduce, crashes immediately on a null pointer deference on my end.

Comment: Yes, this is just a bit of code and I need the functor call in public.
And yes, i assume my program is the issue.. not the compiler. But i dont know where is the issue..

Comment: But it doesnt have to be in constructor, so it means that i should do for loop outside of constructor??

Comment: I think you misunderstand something essential about objects and how they are passed or used... In `Callback::operator()` you create a brand ***new*** and distinct `Boxbot` object, named `b`. This is completely independent from the object created in the `main` function. That `b` object is not properly initialized. You need to pass the actual `Boxbot` object to the `Callback::operator()` function as an argument.

Comment: And I'm not really sure why you have `Callback` and the `callbacks` object to begin with. Why not `for (int i=0;i<3;i++) { bgoals[i]=check_goal(cgoals_[i]); }` directly, if that's supposed to initialize the `bgoals` member.

Comment: Yes, i know... sorry this code I just extract for the test so it may be confusing.
What id like to do is to pass the function object into public to create a subscription from a topic. And the function object needs to be created in private to communicate with a robot.

Comment: It's really hard to properly reach an enclosing object from its member (reach the `Boxbot` from its `callbacks`). You can do it by storing a pointer to the former in the latter, but then if you copy/move the `Boxbot` the pointer will go stale (not to mention the memory wasted on the pointer). Just don't do it if possible.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Thank you, now i understand what is the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *two* problems, one leading to the other.

The first problem is that you have an infinite recursion of `Boxbot` creations.

In the `main` function you create one `Boxbot` object.

In the `Boxbot` class you have

```
struct Callback 
{
    void operator() (int i) const {
        Boxbot b;   // Here you create another Boxbot object
        b.bgoals[i]=b.check_goal(b.cgoals_[i]);
        std::printf("%s is %i\n",b.topicns[i].data(),b.bgoals[i]);
    }
} callbacks;
```

In the `operator()` function you create another `Boxbot` object. And this operator is called in the `Boxbot` constructor. So every `Boxbot` object creation will lead to another Boxbot` object creation. Forever, or until you get a stack overflow.

---

The second problem comes because the constructor defaults the arguments to be a null pointer (`Goal cgoals[]=0` as an argument is really  `Goal* cgoals=0`) your recursive object creations will have a null-pointer access when you copy the `Goal` objects. That leads to *undefined behavior* and a likely crash.

---

And I'm not really sure why you have `Callback` and the `callbacks` object to begin with. Your constructor could just be:

```
Boxbot(Goal* cgoals) 
{
    if (cgoals == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        cgoals_[i] = cgoals[i];
        bgoals[i] = check_goal(cgoals_[i]);
    }
}
```

No recursion, no null-pointer access, and only one loop needed.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what is the problem.